# Problems building Drools 4 project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, building

I'm having trouble compiling a drools 4 project. I'm getting errors in the rules file saying

```
Only a type can be imported. <<MyClassName>> resolves to a package
```

The incremental compiler isn't working because of this. How do I fix the errors or get eclipse to ignore them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmmm, I cleaned the project and that resolved the problem.

Comment: It's a bit of a jerk move to accept your own answer from your own mistake :/

Answer (score 2):

This issue was mentioned for a migration from [drools 3.06 to 4.0.7](http://www.nabble.com/Repast-S-and-Drools-td16158550.html), so what version of eclipse and drools are you using?

This might be related to a [classpath issue](http://www.nabble.com/Repast-S-and-Drools-td16158550.html):

> Using the debugger I realized that the Drools `PackageBuilder` tried to load the classes from the

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

> This `ClassLoader` does not contain my agent classes! Even the system class loader does not contain my classes.

The solution was:

> Instead of creating plain `PackageBuilder` and `RuleBase` instances, one has to create them with a `PackageBuilderConfiguration` and a `RuleBaseConfiguration` both with the current `classLoader` configured:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

PackageBuilderConfiguration configuration = new PackageBuilderConfiguration();
configuration.setClassLoader(classLoader);

PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder(configuration);

builder.addPackageFromDrl(source);

RuleBaseConfiguration ruleBaseConfiguration = new RuleBaseConfiguration();
ruleBaseConfiguration.setClassLoader(classLoader);

ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase(ruleBaseConfiguration);
ruleBase.addPackage(builder.getPackage());
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. My work collegue has just informed me that we didn't migrate and that we have always been on Drools version 4. Sorry, I should have made this clear to save you typing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the MyClassName or any other class(es) that you use from the rule are in a jar file and the jar file is in classpath.