# Play! framework [1.2.4] with Drools on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, drools

I've tried to make simple web app integrated with Drools rule engine and deployed it on heroku. In controller action I'm executing method which imports and parses DRL file, and returns result. I've noticed weird behaviour. When I start app by command `play run` Drools don't want to work (I get some rule import errors and parse knowledge exception), but when I launch my app through Eclipse everything is working.

I've checked what exactly is executed through these different ways:

- Eclipse executes: http://pastebin.com/RK7mnQ81
- `play run` executes: http://pastebin.com/UH1rD7pb

I've tried to run `play run` with extra Java arguments existing in Eclipse execution, but I haven't found working combination.

Any ideas what arguments add to command `play run` to find working solution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    at drools.RuleEngine.readKnowledgeBase(RuleEngine.java:66)
    at drools.RuleEngine.run(RuleEngine.java:28)
    at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:220)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: what are the errors? stacktrace?

Comment: What classes are going into eclipse/classes?

Comment: @szemek can you please elaborate iam also facing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @szemek i myself finally resolved the problem........ i have spent around 2 days to debug and finish it off..........But it looks weird knowing  drools is not able to detect the play models?

Comment: Code with some fixes works fine on Play! 2.0-beta.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a solution for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083303/894060
I've packed Drools-related classes and rule file in one jar file and I put that jar in one directory included in `classpath` -- it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> > I have no idea how to make a workaround/hack to get it worked.

I did the following to resolve the problem.I have added the following line to the file **play\framework\pym\play\application.py**  in the method **def getClasspath(self):**

```
        classpath.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.join(self.path, 'tmp'),'classes')))
```

The above just adds the classes which are their in the play tmp > classes directory to the classpath.

Everything works fine.

But i really didn't understand how play is able to resolve these references where as Drools is failing to do so.

Comment: Ok, your solution is fine but it won't work when I deploy my app to heroku. I'd like to change only my app code and configuration.